# Strange error in Asp.Net Core 5.0 on Linux "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')"

Tags: asp.net, linux, database, apache, deployment

Im blocked since one week with that error.

> "An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')"

I deployed an application in Asp.Net Core in Apache on Linux.

I can access to the pages but when it needs to call the database it gives me that error.

When I use it locally on my windows everything work and I can access to the database with the same connectionString.

I dont understand why it doesnt work when I build the project and I deploy it.

Can somebody help me please.

Here is my connection string:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=IP SERVER;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=SA;Password=Password"
},
```

I already deployed that app on Azure with an SQL database on azure, maybe it's because of that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using net core, the  connection string is kept in appsettings.json file. The default JsonConfigurationProvider loads configuration in the following order:

1. appsettings.json
2. appsettings.Environment.json . For example, the appsettings.Production.json and appsettings.Development.json files.

appsettings.Environment.json values override keys in appsettings.json:

In development, appsettings.Development.json configuration overwrites values found in appsettings.json.

In production, appsettings.Production.json configuration overwrites values found in appsettings.json. For example, when deploying the app to Azure or any another server.

So you have to check appsettings.Production.json file.  Maybe it doesn't containg connection string and since overrides your development file you can have the error.

UPDATE

If you use MS SQl server your connection string should look like this, but I don't think that it is a problem. Problem could be if you use  a different name, instead of "DefaultConnection"

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=xx.182.xx.xxx;Initial catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=passwod;"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

I checked the files you told me, and I dont find "appsetings.Production.json" 
I still have only an appsettings.Development.json and appsetings.json after publishing

Comment: @Edenn Check appsettings and find a connection string. If it is ok, you can make a copy of appsetiings and rename it  to appsetings.Production.json". After this you will have to restart website.

Comment: I did it but it still give me the same error...

I seriously don't understand why but thank you for your help !

Comment: @Eq Did you find the connection string there?  Does it have the same name as in your applilction?

Comment: yes exactly the same file with the same configurations who work when I run on local... 

I was thinking if its because I already deployed that application on Azure with a database form Azure ?? Maybe it's still waiting a connectionString from azure...

Comment: @Edenn But local connection string is usually for local host or  a development server. I don't know what else it can be.  The last thing I am usually trying is to restart everytning that can be restarted.

Comment: Yes I tried everything but I think its not possible to resolve that problem

Thank you for your help